# What happens with GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT|GMEM_FIXED, 0)

Tags: c, windows

Documentation for `malloc` from the WINAPI states whet happens with `malloc(0)`.
The MSDN documentation does not state the behavior for a `GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT|GMEM_FIXED, 0)`. Does it returns a pointer to an allocated memory with data size of 0?

Comment: The `GlobalAlloc` function is guaranteed to either succeed in which case it returns a valid non-zero pointer. Otherwise it will return `NULL`. That means the behavior is predicable and you can easily test this by trying it. If it returns `NULL` then check `GetLastError` to see what error you get. Otherwise you get a pointer to some memory which have been allocated for *at least* "zero" bytes (the documentation says you can use `GlobalSize` to get the actual size allocated).

Comment: Curious that the docs say, for the `GMEM_MOVABLE` flag: *"This value cannot be combined with GMEM_FIXED."* But `GMEM_FIXED` is `0x0000` ... ‎

Comment: @AdrianMole Microsoft...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a runnable program that should answer your question:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT, 0);
    char text[256];
    if (hGlobal == NULL) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, err, 0, text, 256, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", text);
    }
    else {
        size_t nAlloc = GlobalSize(hGlobal);
        printf("Allocated %zu byte(s).\n", nAlloc);
        GlobalFree(hGlobal);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled (as `C` code) with `MSVC` in Visual Studio 2019. This is the output:

```
Allocated 1 byte(s).
```

---

Just to check, you can change the first line to:

```c
    HANDLE hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT, -1);
```

Then, the output is (as expected):

```
Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.
```

Comment: Isn't it impossible to allocate less than a page? A page cannot be 1 byte.

Comment: @Qwark I can find no reference in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc) about any 'granularity' or minimum allocation size. There *may* be such limits - and they *may* be OS-dependent. However, I tested the code I posted and the output I quoted was the *actual* output (this was on a Windows 10 PC, IIRC).

Comment: @Qwark However, from this [kernel allocation doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/allocating-system-space-memory), it seems that you ***can*** allocate less than a page (but probably shouldn't): *Typically, a driver should avoid calling these support routines repeatedly to request allocations of less than PAGE_SIZE because each allocation that is less than PAGE_SIZE also comes with a pool header that is used to internally manage the allocation.*

Comment: I think that it is technically impossible for your OS to allocate less than a PAGE, but Windows can work around that using NonPaged pool that is no more than a trick to reuse the same page. AFAIK according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-pools), non paged pool is only available for drivers to use to store kernel objects.

Comment: @Qwark But I really don't get how this discussion is relevant to your *original* question. You asked what happens and I provided code that shows what happens.

Comment: You are right, closing this question validating your answer.